# How to make floating overlay widget, looks like facebook chat head in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to make floating overlay widget, looks like facebook chat head in flutter??

- Flutter floating overlay widget

i need help guys, What i do now?

- What i'am doing picture

[image: view image]

Comment: Use draggable. Please note it will work only inside the app. Not in home screen

Comment: I need floating overlay widget outside app like facebook chat head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a draggable chat button by checking below link. But it will be inside the application.

Inside app - https://medium.flutterdevs.com/draggable-floating-action-button-in-flutter-2149a7e47f06

If you want to draw the draggable view outside the application, check https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window plugin. Here, you need to do minor tweeks.

Apart from this, other approach is to write the code in native and access it to flutter via method channel
For native - https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064

Comment: Thank you, i can use this with flutter method channel right?

Comment: Yes you need to call the methods to create the chat head from the flutter.